# Cant get flip counter to animate from SQL data

Tags: javascript, html, css, adodb

I am currently working on implementing a flip counter inside of a webpage. I have the overall layout and everything configured and when I load the page the initial live sqlserver data is immediately displayed. I am trying to create an infinite loop that calls a function to reconnect to the db, get the numeric data that I want and reanimate the flip counter to reflect the updated number. It appears that I can re-call the function but the counter never reanimates with the new number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <!-- Counter script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flipcounter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.21954.js"></script>
    <!-- Counter styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

    <!-- NOT REQUIRED FOR COUNTER TO FUNCTION, JUST FOR DEMO PURPOSES -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-  ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700">

    <style>
        html { 
            background: url(images/1_1_1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;     
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <ul id="style-switcher">
        <li><a href="#" class="active" data-style="default">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-style="light">Light</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-style="small">Small</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-style="huge">Huge</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="counter-wrapper">
            <ul class="flip-counter default" id="myCounter"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>    
        $(function () {
            //var myCounter = new flipCounter('myCounter', {value: 1000, inc: 123, pace: 1000, auto: true});
            var myCounter = new flipCounter('myCounter', { value: pull_visit_count(), inc: 0, pace: 0, auto: false }); 

            setInterval(pull_visit_count, 30000);

            function pull_visit_count() {           
                var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
                var connectionstring = ("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; User ID = ; Password = ; Provider = ");

                connection.Open(connectionstring);

                var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

                rs.Open("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE", connection);
                rs.MoveFirst
                while (!rs.eof) {
                    var cnt = parseInt(rs.fields(0));
                    rs.movenext;
                }

                rs.close;
                connection.close;
                return cnt;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Corresponding javascript

```
var flipCounter = function(d, options){

    // Default values
    var defaults = {
        value: 0,
        inc: 1,
        pace: 1000,
        auto: true,
        decimals: 0,
        places: 0
    };

    var counter = options || {};
    var doc = window.document;

    for (var opt in defaults) {
        counter[opt] = counter.hasOwnProperty(opt) ? counter[opt] : defaults[opt];
    }

    var digitsOld = [], digitsNew = [],decimalsOld = [], decimalsNew = [], digitsAnimate = [], x, y, nextCount = null;

    var div = d;
    if (typeof d === 'string') {
        div = doc.getElementById(d);
    }

    /**
    * Sets the value of the counter and animates the digits to new value.
    *
    * Example: myCounter.setValue(500); would set the value of the counter to 500,
    * no matter what value it was previously.
    *
    * @param {int} n
    *   New counter value
    */
    this.setValue = function(n) {
        if (_isNumber(n)) {
            x = counter.value;
            y = counter.value = n;
            _digitCheck(x, y);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Sets the increment for the counter. Does NOT animate digits.
    */
    this.setIncrement = function(n) {
        counter.inc = _isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.inc;
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Sets the pace of the counter. Only affects counter when auto == true.
    *
    * @param {int} n
    *   New pace for counter in milliseconds
    */
    this.setPace = function(n) {
        counter.pace = _isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.pace;
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Sets counter to auto-increment (true) or not (false).
    *
    * @param {boolean} a
    *   Should counter auto-increment, true or false
    */
    this.setAuto = function(a) {
        var sa = typeof a !== "boolean" ? true : a;
        if (counter.auto) {
            if (!sa) {
                if (nextCount) {
                    _clearNext();
                }
                counter.auto = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (sa) {
                if (nextCount) {
                    _clearNext();
                }
                counter.auto = true;
                _doCount();
            }
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Increments counter by one animation based on set 'inc' value.
    */
    this.step = function() {
        if (!counter.auto) {
            _doCount();
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Adds a number to the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
    *
    * @param {int} n
    *   Number to add to counter value
    */
    this.add = function(n) {
        if (_isNumber(n)) {
            x = counter.value;
            counter.value += n;
            y = counter.value;
            _digitCheck(x, y);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Subtracts a number from the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
    *
    * @param {int} n
    *   Number to subtract from counter value
    */
    this.subtract = function(n) {
        if (_isNumber(n)) {
            x = counter.value;
            counter.value -= n;
            if (counter.value >= 0) {
                y = counter.value;
            } else {
                y = "0";
                counter.value = 0;
            }
            _digitCheck(x, y);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * Gets current value of counter.
    */
    this.getValue = function() {
        return counter.value;
    };

    /**
    * Stops all running increments.
    */
    this.stop = function() {
        if (nextCount) {
            _clearNext();
        }
        return this;
    };

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    function _doCount(first) {
        var first_run = typeof first === "undefined" ? false : first;

        x = counter.value.toFixed(counter.decimals);

        if (!first_run) {
            counter.value += counter.inc;
        }
        y = counter.value.toFixed(counter.decimals);
        _digitCheck(x, y);
        // Do first animation
        if (counter.auto === true) {
            nextCount = setTimeout(_doCount, counter.pace);
        }
    }

    function _digitCheck(x, y) {
        if(counter.decimals) {
            x = x.toString().split('.');
            y = y.toString().split('.');

            decimalsOld = _toArray(x[1]);
            decimalsNew = _toArray(y[1]);
            digitsOld = _toArray(x[0]);
            digitsNew = _toArray(y[0]);
        } else {
            digitsOld = _toArray(x);
            digitsNew = _toArray(y);
        }

        var ylen = digitsNew.length;
        var dlen = 0;
        if(counter.decimals) {
            ylen += decimalsNew.length;
            dlen = decimalsNew.length;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < ylen; i++) {        
            if (i < dlen) {
                digitsAnimate[i] = decimalsNew[i] != decimalsOld[i];
            } else {
                var j = i - dlen;
                digitsAnimate[i] = digitsNew[j] != digitsOld[j];
            }
        }
        _drawCounter();
    }

    // Creates array of digits for easier manipulation
    function _toArray(input) {
        var output = input.toString().split('').reverse();
        if (counter.places > 0 && output.length < counter.places) {
            for (var i = output.length; i < counter.places; i++) {
                output.push('0');
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    // Sets the correct digits on load
    function _drawCounter() {
        var bit = 1, html = '', dNew, dOld;

        var i = 0;
        if (counter.decimals) {
            for (i = 0; i < counter.decimals; i++) {
                dNew = _isNumber(decimalsNew[i]) ? decimalsNew[i] : '';
                dOld = _isNumber(decimalsOld[i]) ? decimalsOld[i] : '';
                html += 
                    '<li class="digit" id="'+d+'-digit-a'+i+'">'+
                        '<div class="line"></div>'+
                        '<span class="front">'+dNew+'</span>'+
                        '<span class="back">'+dOld+'</span>'+
                        '<div class="hinge-wrap"><div class="hinge">'+
                            '<span class="front">'+dOld+'</span>'+
                            '<span class="back">'+dNew+'</span>'+
                        '</div></div>'+
                    '</li>';
            }
            html += '<li class="digit-delimiter">.</li>'
        }

        var count = digitsNew.length;
        for (i; i < digitsAnimate.length; i++) {
            var j = i - (digitsAnimate.length - digitsNew.length);
            dNew = _isNumber(digitsNew[j]) ? digitsNew[j] : '';
            dOld = _isNumber(digitsOld[j]) ? digitsOld[j] : '';

            html += 
                '<li class="digit" id="'+d+'-digit-a'+i+'">'+
                    '<div class="line"></div>'+
                    '<span class="front">'+dNew+'</span>'+
                    '<span class="back">'+dOld+'</span>'+
                    '<div class="hinge-wrap"><div class="hinge">'+
                        '<span class="front">'+dOld+'</span>'+
                        '<span class="back">'+dNew+'</span>'+
                    '</div></div>'+
                '</li>';

            if (bit !== count && bit % 3 === 0) {
                html += '<li class="digit-delimiter">,</li>';
            }
            bit++;
        }

        div.innerHTML = html;

        var alen = digitsAnimate.length;

        // Need a slight delay before adding the 'animate' class or else animation won't fire on FF
        setTimeout(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < alen; i++) {
                if (digitsAnimate[i]) {
                    var a = doc.getElementById(d+'-digit-a'+i);
                    a.className = a.className+' animate';
                }
            }
        }, 20)
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844
    function _isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    function _clearNext() {
        clearTimeout(nextCount);
        nextCount = null;
    }

    // Start it up
    _doCount(true); 
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of code for a flip counter. If I were you, I would scrap this and check out socket.io or firebase for real-time page updates instead of long polling like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are updating the counter object's value anywhere.

Does changing

```
setInterval(pull_visit_count, 30000);
```

to

```
setInterval(function() {
    myCounter.setValue(pull_visit_count());
}, 30000);
```

work?

Comment: yes this was exactly what I needed I cant believe I didnt catch that.

Comment: Now I just need to understand why, when it does get the new value only half of the flip counter changes to reflect it until the next query runs, then the other half "flips" to the new value.

Comment: I would start by using the debugger in your browser to step through the code in the `_drawCounter` and `_digitCheck` methods; `_digitCheck` is called at the end of the `setValue` method and `_drawCounter` is called at the end of `_digitCheck`.